# How to set value to <p> in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the value to a paragraph element in code behind so that the result would be like the following:

```
 <p runat="server" id="txtShutDown"><!--#include File="ShutDown.inc"--></p>
```

I tried:

```
txtShutDown.InnerText = "<!--#include File=\"ShutDown.inc\"-->";
```

and

```
txtShutDown.InnerHtml = "<!--#include File=\"ShutDown.inc\"-->";
```

but neither works.

Comment: I just tried setting it on Page_Load and it works. Where are you setting this? If possible, can you post some more details.

Comment: @curiousgeek  I have tried it in Page_load as well.  But instead of the content of the file 'shutdown.inc' I see the literal string. By the way, did you try the .InnerText or InnerHtml?

Comment: You definitely can't see the content of that file by setting like this. You need to read the file in your code behind and set the string value.

Comment: @curiousgeek Fair enough.  I will work on a different approach.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm actually surprised this works at all, to be honest!)

That the ASP.NET ASPX file parser supports SSI (Server-side include) syntax as a legacy of Classic ASP 3.0 (and is also very under-documented too). I'm surprised it works at all and I'm curious what the rendered result of your first example is as it is mixing a `HtmlControl` instance (`HtmlGenericControl("p")`) with SSI. I imagine the contents of `ShutDown.inc` are set as static text content of the `<p>` by the parser and that attempting to include another `.aspx` file will result in a parsing error as it will encounter a `@Page` directive twice.

The "include" process happens earlier-on in the ASP.NET pipeline by the ASPX parser itself. You cannot invoke this operation later-on in the ASP.NET page pipeline/lifetime.

If you want to do a raw text include then you need to do it manually, like so:

```
String path = this.Server.MapPath("~/ShutDown.inc");
txtShutDown.InnerHtml = File.ReadAllText( path );
```